# Not able to create DFS namespace in a completely new forest

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, dfs, dfs-r

Not able to create DFS namespace in a completely new forest

OS: Windows server 2016
DFL: 2003
FFL: 2003
DFS role on member server 
creating very first namespace server - Errors in : The object identifier does not represent a valid object.

Have already tried clearing the container in ADSIedit,
Clearing Registry keys:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DfsHost
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DfsDriver\LocalVolumes
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Dfs\Roots\Domain\xxx
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\serivces\LanmanServer\Shares
```

and tried re-creating but it fails.

What could be stopping it for namespace creation?? any ideas, two days already spent on this.

and another thing is why do sometimes I keep getting RPC server unavailable?? Windows Firewall is off.

Would really appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: I guess you have a trust between your forest ? is it working good ? (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc737447(v=ws.10))

Comment: Trust is good but I am not sure trust will cause any issue in creating DFS namespace

Comment: Antivirus is now disabled and able to create Namespace from domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus is now disabled and able to create Namespace from domain controller.

You may close this thread.

Comment: Which antivirus?? Windows Defender??